# turning airplane mode on and off and how to turn on mobile data in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I use this code for turning on airplane mode on android:

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 1);
        newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
        newIntent.putExtra("state", true);
        context.sendBroadcast(newIntent);
```

It works on API 16 but on API 23 doesn't work and application terminates. What should I do?

And second question is: How to turn on and off mobile data in android without root?

Comment: Turning *on* mobile data/turning *off* airplane mode seem like particularly bad things for an app to be able to do. The reverse operations seem like annoying things to be able to do, but at least they're not bad.

Answer (score 0):

As per [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#AIRPLANE_MODE_ON) Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON constant is deprecated since API Level 17 and onwards, That's why your application is crashing. 
You should use [Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#AIRPLANE_MODE_ON) instead.

Comment: I used that but it stills crashing.

Comment: exactly what is the error? post your error stack trace with the question.

Comment: How could it be possible? Debug your app, you will surely get some error messages.. is the app restarting after termination?

Comment: I debugged but nothing shows. And app does not restart.